# How do you add annotations to an image in Qt?

Tags: image, qt

Does Qt support textual annotations of images as part of its object library?

Comment: Can you refine what you mean by this?  Qt has a Graphics View framework which lets you lay down all kinds of objects on an abstract surface you can scale and rotate...even write Visio-style things.  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/examples-graphicsview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to write text on the image, `QImage` is a child class of `QPaintDevice` initialising a `QPainter` with your image lets you draw on top of the image with any of the functions `QPainter` offers including `drawText()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Exif data? Qt does not support it. You can only add a "comment" tag to images. Look at QImageWriter documentation (QImageWriter::setText)

```
QImage image("some/image.jpeg");
QImageWriter writer("images/outimage.png", "png");
writer.setText("Author", "John Smith");
writer.write(image);
```